# Expresso Store: Routinely import inventory from third party source

Tags: ecommerce, expresso, import

I have a question that pertains to Expresso.

We have a client that wants e-commerce and a new website. We'e already sold them on the importance of a CMS for the job they want done and naturally we also recommended Expresso. But it gets a bit complicated from this point..

They have an AS400 Mainframe that they use to keep all of their pertinent data, like inventory. They have the know how and expertise to expose this data to us, but the big question is "how do we get it into Expresso?"

There's the data import plugin here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/data-import

But I'm not sure it can specifically meet our needs. Does anyone have a recommendation for how to achieve this?

tdlr; takeaway:

Inventory data from AS400 mainframe must be injected into Expresso. 
Client have resources on hand to expose data in whatever way we want (xml file, sql, whatever).
How do we get it into Expresso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [DataGrab](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) for the same thing. As of the current version, only Store 1 is supported, however, it's fairly easy to modify the Store datatype to support Store 2.

Once you set up the import in DataGrab, it provides you a URL which you can hit with cron to regularly import updates.

Comment: Oh this is marvelous. Could you please explain concerning Store1 and Store2?

Comment: The fieldtype file for Store (ajw_datagrab/fieldtypes/datagrab_store.php) which allows Datagrab to import to Store's product field, is built for the 1.x version of store. The field structure (how the data for a store field is stored in the database) has changed for Store 2.x and the file needs to be updated to work with the new version, which involves reviewing the new field names from the publish page and updating them. Info about progress on an official updated version is here: http://brandnewbox.co.uk/forums/viewthread/885/